SIM7600 module sends 'CLOSED' after CIPOPEN command send
SIM7600 module sends 'CLOSED' after CIPOPEN command sending.
Sometimes it is responding as +CIPEVENT: NETWORK CLOSED UNEXPECTEDLY
Why it is sending CLOSED and what are the commands we need to send to open ans send data to server in data mode
Why it is sending CLOSED and what are the commands we need to send to open ans send data to server in data mode

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
